# Javascript RegExp: Best Buy product ID from URL

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a Best Buy URL:

```
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Microsoft+-+Xbox+360+4GB+Console+-+Black/1162184.p?id=1218228678498&skuId=1162184
```

How can I use Javascript to grab the 13 digit product ID:

```
1218228678498
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: `/\?.*id=([0-9]{13})/`

Use [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) to test your regexes :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working:

```
var url = "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Microsoft+-+Xbox+360+4GB+Console+-+Black/1162184.p?id=1218228678498&skuId=1162184";

//look for fist question mark in the url, then for id property as a first capture group
var regx = /\?.*?id=(.*?)&/g;

//get first group match
var id = regx.exec(url)[1]);
```

This regexp will grab any id HTTP query parameter from any URL.